# Sqlite trigger is not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, timestamp

I'm trying to achieve automatic timestamps updating, when status of some devices is changed.
I have a table like this for devices:

```
CREATE TABLE devices(
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  status text,
  "timestamp" datetime,
  FOREIGN KEY (timestamp) REFERENCES timestamps (controls)
);
```

This is table for timestamps:

```
CREATE TABLE timestamps (
  "database" datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  controls datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
);
```

When I try this trigger, and modify `status` column for rows in `devices` table, I don't see anything changes in `timestamps` table (particularly it is blank as it was).

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_timestamps UPDATE OF status ON devices 
BEGIN
  UPDATE timestamps SET controls=datetime('now');
END;
```

Could you please have a look what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have any record in timestamps table. The trigger really works as desired. See the output below:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE devices(
   ...>   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   ...>   status text,
   ...>   "timestamp" datetime,
   ...>   FOREIGN KEY (timestamp) REFERENCES timestamps (controls)
   ...> );

sqlite> CREATE TABLE timestamps (
   ...>   "database" datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
   ...>   controls datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
   ...> );

sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER update_timestamps UPDATE OF status ON devices
   ...> BEGIN
   ...>   UPDATE timestamps SET controls=datetime('now');
   ...> END;
sqlite>
```

Insert data into devices and timestamps table

```
sqlite> insert into devices (status, "timestamp") values ('test',' 2011-05-05');
sqlite> select * from devices;
|test| 2011-05-05
sqlite>
sqlite> insert into timestamps values ('2010-01-01', '2010-01-01');
sqlite> select * from timestamps;
2010-01-01|2010-01-01
```

Perform the update and notice trigger changing data in timestamps;

```
sqlite>
sqlite> update devices set status = 'test1';
sqlite>
sqlite> select * from devices;
|test1| 2011-05-05
sqlite> select * from timestamps;
2010-01-01|2015-10-05 20:47:05
```

You could insert data instead of doing an update in the trigger like so:

```
sqlite> create trigger insert_data_into_timestsamp update of status on devices
   ...> begin
   ...>   insert into timestamps values (datetime('now'), datetime('now'));
   ...> end;
sqlite>
sqlite> select * from devices;
|test1| 2011-05-05
sqlite> select * from timestamps;
2010-01-01|2015-10-05 20:47:05
sqlite>
sqlite> drop trigger update_timestamps;
```

Let's update status 3 times

```
sqlite> update devices set status = 'test';
sqlite> update devices set status = 'test1';
sqlite> update devices set status = 'test2';
```

Notice that 3 records were entered

```
sqlite> select * from timestamps;
2010-01-01|2015-10-05 20:47:05
2015-10-05 20:50:20|2015-10-05 20:50:20
2015-10-05 20:50:25|2015-10-05 20:50:25
2015-10-05 20:50:26|2015-10-05 20:50:26
```

Comment: But why is there no timestamps? I specified `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for those columns

Comment: Good question. `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` means that when you do an `INSERT`, if there is no data provided for that column, current timestamp will be used.

Comment: Still not clear for me, as you noted `current timestamp will be used`, so I expect sqlite to insert current time into the columns by itself. Is that not correct?

Comment: That is not how DEFAULT works in table declaration. If you wrote `insert into timestamps DEFAULT VALUES;`, a record with default data will be entered. If you wrote `update` statement, the database updates existing row(s) that match a filter (if `where` clause is provided). Since you have no records, `update` doesn't do anything.